# Reset Running total when either column value changes using Oracle Analytics

Tags: oracle

I wants to add a column to the view which keeps a running total of the Value column.  This column must reset the running total when either Cat A or Cat B changes in the rows.
So the output data must be like this:-

```
CAT A  CAT B    Value   Running Total
=====  =====    =====   =============
0        1       15 
0        1       235 
0        1       306      556
0        0        
1        2       85        85
1        1       105      105 
0        2       600
0        2       70       670
0        3       564
0        3       101      665
0        1       30        30
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* result sets.  A "running total" suggests and ordering.  What column specifies the ordering?  Also, your running sum is missing values.  There should be values on the rows that are blank for a "running" sum.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a column to specify the ordering for the running sum.  I will assume this is called `id`.

Second, you seem to have some logic that does not have values on certain rows.  It is not clear what this logic is.  A proper "running sum" would be defined on all rows.

Then, you can use `lag()` and `sum()` to define the groups and use "analytic" `sum()` for the running sum:

```
select t.cata, t.catb, t.value,
       sum(value) over (partition by grp order by id) as runningsum
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when cata = prev_cata and catb = prev_catb then 0
                      else 1
                  end) over (order by id) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(cata) over (order by id) as prev_cata,
                   lag(catb) over (order by id) as prev_catb
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gordon. I also have date column which I will be using for ordering running sum. And yes I want hide the running sum (if possible) until the row columns value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Reset in a partition can be done by introducing a new column that will enable the partition split. In your case if you create a new column that have a unique value based either CAT A or CAT B change, this will allow you run analytic function at subset level, you partition will include your already using one + this new column...this essentially does the reset you are looking for